# Access object in geojson properties for label

Tags: mapbox

I'm new to mapbox studio and trying to access data in the properties of my uploaded geojson.

Data is successfully added to my style as two layers. Layer one is for the red dots as added as circles and layer two is for the labels as symbols.

As seen here this works fine for values which are directly in the properties object:

[image: correctly displayed data]

Unfortunately it is not possible to display data which is in an object inside the properties object:

[image: wrong display of object as symbol]

My question is, how can I access these values?

Comment: You should add relevant code to your question, looking at images does not help.

Comment: You likely need to parse the object in your properties (either "busType" or "qualifier".  Can you post an example of your GeoJson data structure.  e.g.,   {"type":"Feature",
    "properties":{"name":"text"},"geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[0.1, 2.3]}
  }